# I can't insert data into my database while in a Session

Tags: php, html

I have the tables `users` and `register` in my database. I've created a login page which starts a session using the `users` table, then people fill out a form to insert data into the `register` table. I've used the following code to insert the data. My code doesn't have errors but the thing is it is not inserted to my table. Please help me. Thanks.

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){        
        header("location: login.php");
    }
    else { ?>
    <html>
    <body>
        <h2>New users Signup!</h2>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name = "firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
            <input type="text" name = "lastname" placeholder="Lastname"/>
            <input type="text" name = "address" placeholder="Address"/>
            <input type="text" name = "contact" placeholder="Contact"/>
            <input type="text" name = "email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            <input type="password" name = "password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <div class = "bttn">
            <button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $users_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $users_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $users_address = $_POST['address'];
        $users_contact = $_POST['contact'];
        $users_email = $_POST['email'];
        $users_password = $_POST['password'];
        $users_date = date('Y-m-d');

        if($users_firstname=='' or $users_lastname=='' or $users_address=='' or $users_contact=='' or $users_email=='' or $users_password=='')
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Any of the fields is empty')</script>";
            exit();
        } else {
            $insert_query = mysql_query("insert into users (users_firstname,users_lastname,users_address,users_contact,users_email,users_password,users_date) values ('$users_firstname','$users_lastname','$users_address','$users_contact','$users_email','$users_password','$users_date')");
            $users_id=mysql_insert_id();

            if(mysql_query($insert_query)) {
                echo "<script>alert('post published successfuly')</script>";
            }
        }
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: use action="#" seems like, you are using the same file as an action to that form.. so no need to call the file name there.. a # is enough..

Comment: what is that `if(mysql_query($insert_query))` , you already run query in $insert_query

Comment: Have you tried error checking?

Comment: "*My code doesn't have errors*" - it would work if there were no errors ;-) You just need to check for them, see these functions: [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), 
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) and [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and removed entirely in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can.

Comment: @DavidJawphan that is to confirm if the query really works or the values were really inserted inthe database. Sorry dude im just new to this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should removed the whitespaces in your html-code:

   **Wrong**

   ```
     <input type="text" name = "firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
                           ^^^^^
   ```

   **Correct**

   ```
     <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
   ```
2. <s>Do not put the variables in single quotes:</s>

   ```
   $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users 
   (users_firstname,users_lastname,users_address,users_contact,users_email,users_password,users_date) 
   VALUES 
   ($users_firstname,$users_lastname,$users_address,$users_contact,$users_email,$users_password,$users_date)");
   ```

*Update: This was wrong. The whole string is in double-quotes so the OP did correct and my notice was wrong. For information-purposes i will let stand the link to the documentation here.*

> **Note**: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Read more about single- and double-quotes in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

3. Do not double-run the query/perform wrong function-call

   ```
   $insert_query = mysql_query(".......");
   ........
   if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
       echo "<script>alert('post published successfuly')</script>";
   }
   ```

   You already have run the query in the first line. If you want to check if it was successful, you have to use `if($insert_query) {}`. The call `mysql_query($insert_query)` is wrong because [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a ressource instead of the sql-query.
4. Do not use `mysql_*()` function calls. You `mysqli_*()` instead.

   > **Warning**
   >   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
   >   mysqli_query()
   >   PDO::query()
5. Check your use of `session`.

You are checking the `$_SESSION` for `user_name` and if it is not set, you are redirecting via `header("location: login.php")`.
The problem is, that you are never inserting the `user_name` into the session, so it will always be not set.

You can set the value via `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name']`. Have in mind that you have to set the session before checking the session-value. ;-)

Comment: 1. That doesn't really matter, it works anyway. 2. Single quotes SHOULD be used around strings in SQL, and the whole thing is put in double-quotes, so variables *are* passed.

Comment: damn you are right, my fault. thanks for the notice. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hey but if i removed if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){

    header("location: login.php");
    }
    else {
it is working

Answer (score 0):

Now try this code:

```
<?php
        include("includes/db.php");
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){

    header("location: login.php");
    }
    else {

    ?>
    <html>
    <body>


        <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

          $users_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
          $users_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
          $users_address = $_POST['address'];
          $users_contact = $_POST['contact'];
          $users_email = $_POST['email'];
          $users_password = $_POST['password'];
          $users_date = date('Y-m-d');

        if($users_firstname=='' or $users_lastname=='' or $users_address=='' or $users_contact=='' or $users_email=='' or $users_password=='')
        {
        echo "<script>alert('Any of the fields is empty')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        else 
        {
            $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (users_firstname, users_lastname, users_address, users_contact, users_email, users_password, users_date) values ('$users_firstname', '$users_lastname', '$users_address', '$users_contact', '$users_email', '$users_password', '$users_date')");
            $users_id=mysql_insert_id();


          echo "<script>alert('post published successfuly')</script>";

        }
    }
    ?>

        <h2>New users Signup!</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname"/>
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"/>
            <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <div class="bttn">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php } ?>
```

I have:

1. Repositioned your PHP code for inserting to be at the top of the form
2. changed `<form action="login.php"` to `<form action=""` because we are executing from the same page
3. Your query has already run so removed the `if(mysql_query...`
4. Removed the spaces in the form e.g. `name = " nameofform"` to name="nameofform"
5. I don't see any reason for having this `$users_id=mysql_insert_id();`, YOu should use auto-increment for the userID on your database

But since **we don't know how you have connected to your database**, because also that can be an issue: you can also try this way

```
 <?php
//connect to DB

$hostname_localhost = "localhost"; //hostname if it is not localhost
$database_localhost = "databasename";
$username_localhost = "root"; //the username if it is not root
$password_localhost = "password_if_any"; //if no password leave empty
$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>

<?php 
    // include("includes/db.php");     
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    header("location: login.php");
    }
    else {
?>
    <html>
    <body>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

          $users_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
          $users_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
          $users_address = $_POST['address'];
          $users_contact = $_POST['contact'];
          $users_email = $_POST['email'];
          $users_password = $_POST['password'];
          $users_date = date('Y-m-d');

        if($users_firstname=='' or $users_lastname=='' or $users_address=='' or $users_contact=='' or $users_email=='' or $users_password=='')
        {
        echo "<script>alert('Any of the fields is empty')</script>";
        exit();
        }

        else 
        {


$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (users_firstname, users_lastname, users_address, users_contact, users_email, users_password, users_date) values ('$users_firstname', '$users_lastname', '$users_address', '$users_contact', '$users_email', '$users_password', '$users_date')");

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$Result = mysql_query($insert_query, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());


          echo "<script>alert('post published successfuly')</script>";

        }
    }
    ?>

        <h2>New users Signup!</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"/>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname"/>
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address"/>
            <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
            <div class = "bttn">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

remove `action`
Try this

```
 <form action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Although it's not needed with an `action` attribute when you're pointing to the same file, it doesn't matter as long as the correct file-name is given.